# Python multiprocessing Pool / Process has inconsistent results

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

My shared dictionary object has an inconsistent number of entries. It should have 500, but most tests end up with somewhere between 450 and 465. I've also tried using `map` and `Process` instead of `apply_async`.

`map` is slightly better because the shared dictionary has around 480 entries instead of around 450, but it's still inconsistent and not all 500 as expected.

I also tried using Process, but that results in the fewest number of entries in my shared dictionary -- around 420.

Here's the full code using `apply_async`:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from os import listdir
from multiprocessing import Manager, Pool

def processImage(path, d):
  image = np.array(Image.open(source + "/" + path))

  # Copy lists from shared dictionary since updates don't work otherwise
  w = d["width"]
  h = d["height"]
  w.append(image.shape[0])
  h.append(image.shape[1])
  d["width"] = w
  d["height"] = h

if __name__ == "__main__":
  source = "./sample/images"
  p = Pool()
  m = Manager()
  d = m.dict()
  d["width"], d["height"] = [], []

  for path in listdir(source):
    p.apply_async(processImage, (path, d))
  p.close()
  p.join()
```

Here's the full code using `map`:

```
def processImage(obj):
  image = np.array(Image.open(source + "/" + obj[1]))

  w = obj[0]["width"]
  h = obj[0]["height"]
  w.append(image.shape[0])
  h.append(image.shape[1])
  obj[0]["width"] = w
  obj[0]["height"] = h

if __name__ == "__main__":
  source = "./sample/images"
  p = Pool()
  m = Manager()
  d = m.dict()
  d["width"], d["height"] = [], []

  p.map(processImage, zip(itertools.repeat(d), listdir(source)))
```

Here's the full code for using `Process`:

```
def processImage(path, d):
  image = np.array(Image.open(source + "/" + path))

  w = d["width"]
  h = d["height"]
  w.append(image.shape[0])
  h.append(image.shape[1])
  d["width"] = w
  d["height"] = h

if __name__ == "__main__":
  source = "./sample/images"
  p = Pool()
  m = Manager()
  d = m.dict()
  d["width"], d["height"] = [], []

  jobs = []
  for img in listdir(source):
    p = Process(target=processImage, args=(img, d))
    p.start()
    jobs.append(p)

  for j in jobs:
    j.join()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is a classic example of a race condition. You need some kind of a synchronization primitive to update `d`.

Consider the following situation: there are two threads (well, subprocesses in your case) executing `processImage`. First obtains `w` and `h`, second obtains `w` and `h`. First appends something to both and puts it back to `d`. Second does something to its own `w` and `h`, which do not account for changes made by the first thread anymore, and puts it back to `d`. At this point, changes made by the first thread are lost.

To fix that, you need to guard parts of the code working with `d`:

```
from multiprocessing import Manager, Pool, Lock
...
lock = Lock()
...
def processImage(path, d):
    image = np.array(Image.open(source + "/" + path))

    lock.acquire()
    d["width"].append(image.shape[0])
    d["height"].append(image.shape[1])
    lock.release()
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation -- it makes sense but, unfortunately, doesn't solve my problem :/

http://imgur.com/a/2eWJ8

Comment: Disregard my comment above, moving the lock acquisition and release to before and after copying the lists solved the problem!